# How to create sql file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 6 tables already created, which I access from mySQL Workbench. Is there any way I can get the query for the creation of the database and all 6 tables inside it? I need this so that I can create that database and all 6 tables on it, on another computer simply by double clicking an sql file. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: export it as .sql file

Comment: And import it to your other computer.

Comment: @monace19 export to dump project folder or self-contained file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: This could help I think. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get SQL File from MYSQL Workbench, you need to do this :

1. Open your model.
2. Click Database menu and choose Forward Engineer.
3. And click next until you show like picture below,
4. Save to file..
   [image]

Comment: Where is forward engineer? I only see reverse engineer.

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam 6.3.3.0 and I'm on Mac OSX

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam Thanks! I didn't create the model, that's why. I created it, forward engineered, and now I have the sql file. Thanks very much. By the way, I have to create the connection manually though on my other computer right?